# SQLAPI linking with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to link my static library files (SQLAPI Library Files) to my project. I've done this before by using VS 2017 but in CLion I couldn't done. Surely, I think my CMake experience is not enough to do this process. Firstly I thought that maybe my CMake doesn't work, then I tried to install OpenCV in same way and it worked.

Basicly my main body;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SQLAPI.h>
int main() {
    SAConnection connection;
    connection.Connect("test","test","test",SA_Oracle_Client);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Therefore here is my CMakeList.txt;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(kutuphanedeneme)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(kutuphanedeneme ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SQLAPI/include)
add_executable(kutuphanedeneme main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(kutuphanedeneme ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SQLAPI/lib/libsqlapi.a)
target_link_libraries(kutuphanedeneme ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SQLAPI/lib/libsqlapiu.a)

#target_link_libraries(kutuphanedeneme ${OpenCV_LIBS})
#target_link_libraries(kutuphanedeneme ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libsqlapi.so)

#message(${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

My error part;

```
Scanning dependencies of target kutuphanedeneme
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable kutuphanedeneme
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Parçalama arızası], core dumped
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: girdi dosyası `CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'kutuphanedeneme' failed
make[3]: *** [kutuphanedeneme] Error 1
make[3]: *** 'kutuphanedeneme' dosyası siliniyor
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/kutuphanedeneme.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'kutuphanedeneme' failed
make: *** [kutuphanedeneme] Error 2
```

Comment: According to answer I can't do anything about this problem i guess i can just report the problem to Linux. I'll try it on CodeBlocks maybe it will work.

Comment: For sure your `ld` is failing. You have to check your installation of Linux.